# Problema ao carregar fonts quando subo o site para o servidor

Tags: html5, css3

Estou usando algumas fonts que guardei dentro de uma pasta no meu sistema. Quando executo o sistema localmente não há nenhum problema, porém quando eu subo o servidor para o servidor (amazon) as fontes param de ser exibidas. Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Esse é o código que estou usando para carregar as fonts no css:

A primeira font está sendo exibida normalmente no servidor, as outras duas só localmente

```
@font-face {

   font-family: 'tipografia';
   src:url("../fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ocr';
  src: url("../fonts/ocra.ttf");
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'bemio';
   src: url("../fonts/bemio.otf");
 }
```

Comment: Você já confirmou se os arquivos de fonte subiram para o servidor Amazon?

Comment: Talvez você precise limpar o cache do navegador para não reaproveitar o css antigo.

Comment: No DevTools do Google Chrome na aba Network vc conferiu se a fonte é carregada. Está aparecendo algum erro?

Comment: Subi as fontes sim #Rodrigo K.B e não é nada relativo ao cache #Sveen, mesmo porque não tinha nada nele antes de eu subir os arquivo para o servidor. Tanto que local está funcionando normalmente